# dynamically create view model with parameter without using autofac

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, autofac

In order to create navigation service in Xamarin using MVVM, in following code `GetPage` function, I am trying to create page object dynamically in `Xamarin` after that I am creating model view of that page and assigning a newly created model view to page's binding context.

```
private static Page GetPage(Type viewModelType)
{

    try
    {
        var pageType = viewModelType.Name.Replace("ViewModel", "Page");
        Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"SEMA.View.{pageType}"));
        page.BindingContext = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelType);             
        if (page.BindingContext == null)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Binding Context is null");

        }

        return page;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);


    }

    return null;
}
```

but the issue with this code is I have parameter in my model view see below.
`MainViewModel(MenuViewModel menuViewModel)` hence app is throwing error

> Default constructor not found for type SEMA.ViewModel.MainViewModel

If I write default constructor then my parameter constructor i.e. `MainViewModel(MenuViewModel menuViewModel)` won't get called.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MenuViewModel _menuViewModel;


    public MainViewModel(MenuViewModel menuViewModel)
    {
        _menuViewModel = menuViewModel;
    }

    public MenuViewModel MenuViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _menuViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            _menuViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

xaml file of main page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:SEMA="clr-namespace:SEMA;assembly=SEMA" 
                  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:SEMA.View" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  x:Class="SEMA.View.MainPage" >
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MenuPage BindingContext="{Binding MenuViewModel}" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

I am trying to create app based on the [xamarin sample provided by xamarin community](https://github.com/Microsoft/SmartHotel360-mobile-desktop-apps/tree/master/src/SmartHotel.Clients/SmartHotel.Clients) where in they have used `autofac` and they are using following code to create page and map it with view model, but I dont want to use autofac hence I am creating view model using Activator `page.BindingContext = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelType);`  and not using `ViewModelBase viewModel = Locator.Instance.Resolve(viewModelType) as ViewModelBase;
page.BindingContext = viewModel;`

```
protected Page CreateAndBindPage(Type viewModelType, object parameter)
{
    Type pageType = GetPageTypeForViewModel(viewModelType);

    if (pageType == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Mapping type for {viewModelType} is not a page");
    }

    Page page = Activator.CreateInstance(pageType) as Page;
    ViewModelBase viewModel = Locator.Instance.Resolve(viewModelType) as ViewModelBase;
    page.BindingContext = viewModel;

    return page;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Activator.CreateInstance` has [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts an array of objects as parameters for the constructor.

```
private static Page GetPage(Type viewModelType, MenuViewModel menuViewModel)
{
    //...
    page.BindingContext = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelType, new object[] { menuViewModel });
    //...
}
```

Comment: True but the issue is how will i route the `MenuViewModel` to `GetPage`

Comment: You don't share where `GetPage` is called, so can't help you with that. I don't know what a `MenuViewModel` is and if it should be global for the app (reused between pages) or unique per page.